# The columns in 'table_XXX' do not match an existing primiary key or UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 simple tables designed as shown below:

Users:

[image]

Categories:

[image]

Now I would like to set the username as foreign key on categories table so this is what I have done but getting the error as shown below:

[image]

Am I doing the right way? Or can anyone suggest me the right way of doing this ?

***NOTE:** I have tried to remove the primary key from the 2 tables and added them back and tried but showing me the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using unique identifiers as your primary keys? By default your primary key will be your clustering key, and you will end up having some real performance headaches using [a GUID as the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)

Comment: @Gareth-Yes I am using the GUID as the primary key but today when I was searching I found exactly what you said as it has some real time issues. So can you suggest me the better way of doing this ?

Comment: Dear Sir "@coder", I have the impression that you have no idea of the basic principles of database design. You are just doing "something", without knowing what to do. Here, you are trying to reference "username" instead of "userid", which breaks perhaps the most basic rule of database design!! I honestly recommend you to take some time and read about database design principles, before you go on with coding. Especially read about **Database normalization**. You will find many literature everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing it the right way - hence the error.  Put userid in your categories table and join to users if you need the name.

In fact, if that field represents the person who created the category, it should be named something like CreatedByUserId.  It should still reference users.userid.

Comment: Baracuk- Yes I have tried it for userid and it worked. Just I have seen some people over the net has suggested they can use any column name as FK

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should.  Depending on the details of your application, your unsuccessful attempt to set up this foreign key might be a blessing in disguise.  The lack of a unique constraint on username could cause other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Impose a `unique constraint` on the `username` column in `Users` table. Then you can create the FK as shown. That said, having `username` in both tables is not a very good design. You should remove `username` and include `userid` in `Categories` table and make that a FK instead.

Answer (score 0):

> A foreign key constraint does not have to be linked only to a primary
>   key constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

*in* [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)

You have to set a constraint in table Users in order to username to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in the table `Categories` the name of the foreign key field.
It seems that it "autowire" fields using their name. What i mean is : change `Categories.username` to `Categories.userid`.

Answer (score 0):

Your column username in the table users must have a unique constraint if you want to set up the foreign key relationship in your screenshot.